# Psycopg2 Issue with Inserting Rows

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am getting the following error when trying to insert via python:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This is the first row I want to insert, as an example:

```
(Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-10-03 00:00:00'),
 'APP-552498',
 'Company Name Lawyer',
 'Funded',
 36500,
 1095.0,
 1.35,
 49275.0,
 15509.0,
 251.0,
 'Daily',
 1825.0,
 196.31,
 78,
 0.0,
 'Law Offices',
 NaT,
 '',
 'CO',
 8.4,
 'Company Name',
 0.7647,
 38003.68,
 7154.34,
 'West',
 33766.0,
 'N')
```

With the aforementioned commands to insert:

```
df_svc_vals = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
c.execute("""INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (%s)""", df_svc_vals[0])
c.executemany("""INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (%s)""", df_svc_vals)
```

**Furthermore, when I actually copy the data into a separate CSV and load into the DB directly, the data inserts correctly.**

I put the first two columns as type date, every column with a number as real, and the strings as character varying. Also, the column with NaT is a date column, it's just a null value (that's the appearance w/in pandas).

How can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: You need `%s` for every column of the table inside of the parens, `(%s)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put "%s" for each values, so you can do it like this (it will produce "INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (%s,%s,%s,....,%s) )

```
"INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES ("+(",".join(["%s"]*len(df_svc_vals[o])))+")"
```

so overall, you can do soemthing like this

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES ("+(",".join(["%s"]*len(df_vals[0])))+")", df_svc_vals)
```